# Convert rows to columns with values based on ranking

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of customers who have several kinds of "accounts", each with a different integer balance, such as

```
CUSTID     AcctType    Balance
12345      Checking    1000
12345      Savings     5000
12345      Investment  3000 
98765      Savings     2000
98765      Checking    8000
98765      Investment  1000 
98765      Retirement  2500
```

I do not know how many accounts a customer may have (it could be anywhere from 1 to 6). I have to create a result showing the Accounts and Balances as columns, in order from highest to lowest, like this:

```
CUSTID     AcctType1    Balance1   AcctType2   Balance2  AcctType3   Balance3  AcctType4   Balance 4
12345      Savings      5000       Investment  3000      Checking    1000
98765      Checking     8000       Retirement  2500      Savings     2000      Investment   1000
```

Any ideas how to create this in SQL Server? (Ideally as a View)

Comment: account type 1 or 2 demarcation is not in your table

Comment: what determines ranking? Are there a finite number of acctType--if so what are they and their respective ranks? Do you ever accept an answer to a question? Hint: pivot or conditional aggregation

Comment: No, those have to be generated by the query; as I said, each customer may have anywhere from 1 to 6 kinds of accounts in the current data.

The client is looking for a list of accounts from left to right for each customer, ranked by the highest balance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `unpivot` the columns first into rows, then `pivot` the rows back into column with row number, something like this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT 
     CAST(CUSTID AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS CUSTID
     ,CAST(AcctType AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS AcctType
     ,CAST(Balance AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS Balance
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [CUSTID] ORDER BY Balance DESC) AS RN
  FROM Data
), unpivoted
AS
(
  SELECT CUSTID, val, col + ' ' + CAST(RN AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS col
  FROM CTE 
  UNPIVOT
  (
    val
    FOR col IN(AcctType, Balance)
  ) AS u
)
SELECT *
FROM unpivoted AS u
PIVOT
(
  MAX(val)
  FOR col IN([AcctType 1], [Balance 1], 
             [AcctType 2], [Balance 2],
             [AcctType 3], [Balance 3],
             [AcctType 4], [Balance 4])
) AS p;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7dc31/17)

---

**Update:**

If you want to make this dynamic for any number of customers, you have to do it dynamically like this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT 
     CAST(CUSTID AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS CUSTID
     ,CAST(AcctType AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS AcctType
     ,CAST(Balance AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS Balance
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [CUSTID] ORDER BY Balance DESC) AS RN
  FROM Data
), Data
AS
(
  SELECT col, MAX(RN) AS RN
  FROM
  (
    SELECT RN, col + CAST(RN AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS col
    FROM CTE 
    UNPIVOT
    (
      val
      FOR col IN(AcctType, Balance)
    ) AS u
  ) AS t
  GROUP BY col
)
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(col)
                      FROM Data
                      ORDER BY RN
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');

SELECT @query = 'WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT 
     CAST(CUSTID AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS CUSTID
     ,CAST(AcctType AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS AcctType
     ,CAST(Balance AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS Balance
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [CUSTID] ORDER BY Balance DESC) AS RN
  FROM Data
), unpivoted
AS
(
  SELECT CUSTID, val, col + CAST(RN AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS col
  FROM CTE 
  UNPIVOT
  (
    val
    FOR col IN(AcctType, Balance)
  ) AS u
)
SELECT *
FROM unpivoted AS u
PIVOT
(
  MAX(val)
  FOR col IN('+ @cols + ')
) AS p;';


EXECUTE(@query);
```

[Dynamic Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7dc31/36)

Comment: Good SQL, but it won't work as a view (DECLARE variables can't be done in a View, etc). Wonder how else I could do it....SP?

Comment: @BrianBattles  Yes indeed, you cannot put dynamic sql in view. It must be stored procedure. You can use the query without dynamic, but It will give you only fixed number of stuff.

Comment: @BrianBattles - Furthermore, you have a variable number of columns so it cannot be view.

Comment: @BrianBattles - You're welcome, if the answer is helpful please accept it :D

Answer (score 1):

If it's a limited amount of columns(as you said 6 per `CUSTID`) then you can use conditional aggregation with `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT t.custID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.rnk = 1 THEN t.accttype END) as accttype1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.rnk = 1 THEN t.balance END) as balance1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.rnk = 2 THEN t.accttype END) as accttype2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.rnk = 2 THEN t.balance END) as balance2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.rnk = 3 THEN t.accttype END) as accttype3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.rnk = 3 THEN t.balance END) as balance3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.rnk = 4 THEN t.accttype END) as accttype4,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.rnk = 4 THEN t.balance END) as balance4,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.rnk = 5 THEN t.accttype END) as accttype5,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.rnk = 5 THEN t.balance END) as balance5,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.rnk = 6 THEN t.accttype END) as accttype6,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.rnk = 6 THEN t.balance END) as balance6
FROM (SELECT s.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY s.custID ORDER BY s.balance DESC) as rnk
      FROM YourTable s) t
GROUP BY t.custID
```

Comment: Really great, sagi! That seems to work just right...saved me a ton of time...I'm still learning about how to get the most out of Pivots